# Why are my two django objects of the same type behaving differently?

Tags: python, django

Help!

I have two objects that i have created using different techniques in django;

```
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> from myproject.models import Building
```

**Method A**

```
>>> content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myproject', model='Building')

>>> content_class = content_type.model_class()

>>> content_query = content_class.objects.raw("Select * from pms_building where name like '%build%' ")

>>> type(content_query)

<class 'django.db.models.query.RawQuerySet'>
>>> content_query[0]
# error ....
# Attribute: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

**Method B**

```
>>> bld = Building.objects.raw("Select * from pms_building where name like '%build%' ")

>>> type(bld)

<class 'django.db.models.query.RawQuerySet'>

>>>bld[0]
<Building: Building A>
```

My question is why are the two objects of the same type behaving differently?

Gath

Comment: My guess would be two different __init__ methods. Use dir(bld) and dir(content_query) to see what they have defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query is only executed when you call `content_query[0]`, so the query will fail at that point if something is wrong with `content_class` for example. At least I noticed that you forgot the `objects` from the first line:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myproject', model='Building')
```

EDIT: I get the "'str' object has no attribute 'items'" error when %-marks are incorrectly interpreted. This fixed it for me:

```
s = "%build%"
content_query = content_class.objects.raw("Select * from pms_building where namelike %s", [s])
```

Comment: *EDIT* Irrelevant, fixed while I was commenting  =P

Comment: sorry typo, had left out the "objects" edited the question, problem still remains

Comment: @gath Both methods are working for me. What Django version and DB are you using?

Comment: @gath I got that error when using the LIKE with %-chars, check my edit.